# How to choose Xcode version, SDK and toolchain to develop for Mac OS X?

Tags: xcode

Recently I installed mac OS Mojave. Now I starts my way with Xcode. So I have an application for which I use Qt5.5.1, this version was build with deployment 10.7 and sdk 10.10. Also I have another Objective-C application which was build with deployment 10.7 and sdk 10.11. I need to build both apps for minimum Mac OS X 10.7 version with any later versions supported. It is situation. Now questions:

1. There is a any difference which Xcode use to build?
2. Which version Xcode is optimal as IDE? AppStore has very negative rating for latest.
3. There is a any difference which toolchain use? Or I always should use one provided with Xcode?
4. Should I use the same SDK as SDK used in base library? Or it is free to use latest?
5. It is ok to use foreign SDK not provided with installed Xcode version?

Now I can build the both applications with latest Xcode and SDK 10.11. Seems no any problem. But I want to be sure that will no any problems to run and use on 10.7. And want to know correct way to decide which Xcode/SDK and when should to use?

P.S. Applications for PC only, no need any iOS support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the most recent version of Xcode that will run on your Mac and the SDK that ships with that version. Currently the most recent version of Xcode is 10.1, which ships with the macOS 10.14 SDK. By using the 10.14 SDK your app can take advantage of the features introduced in macOS 10.14, such as dark mode. If you build your app with the 10.11 SDK, your app won't be able to take advantage of anything Apple added in 10.12, 10.13, and 10.14. For one thing your app won't look good in dark mode on 10.14.

To support 10.7 in your app, you must set the deployment target for your project to 10.7. The deployment target is the earliest OS version your app supports. You also have to make sure your app doesn't use any technologies or call any functions that were added after 10.7. That means no storyboards, no Swift, and no base internationalization for localizing your app to other spoken languages. Making sure your app uses only things that are available in macOS 10.7 is not easy. That is why many apps support only the most recent version of macOS and 1-2 previous versions.

Comment: Oh dark theme. It's real problem. Due such "improvment" now I must choose will app always use light theme or drop 10.7 support or release app in two versions for modern and obsoletes versions of Mac OS. Really Apple has very user unfrendly politics. I hate this.